# Total force acting on a lever

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, drag, calculus

For fun I wanted to calculate the total drag force acting on a lever. Now the drag force is proportional to the velocity. However a lever's velocity is different at different points. Let $x$ be the distance of a point from the fulcrum. Hence:
$$v=x\dot{\theta}$$
And the drag force at every point is then given by:
$$F=\frac{A\rho c_d v^2}{2}=\frac{A\rho c_d x^2\dot{\theta}^2}{2}$$
Where $A$ is the cross sectional area of the object, $c_d$ the drag coefficient and  $\rho$ is the atmospheric density. Now assuming that the sides of the lever are flat (for example a flat plank). Now I had the idea to find the total force using a double integral. One time with respect to x for the width and once with respect to another variable to account for the width of the lever. However for the units to work out I need to devide the force by an area. My question is if that area is the same as $A$ so that it cancels or different? Essential is this the equation for the total force?
$$F_T={\int_b^a}{\int_d^c}\frac{\rho c_d x^2\dot{\theta}^2}{2}dxdy$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the equation for the drag force was dimensionally correct then the units should be already balanced, you removed A (m.m) and you are integrating with respect to x or y (length dimension) twice, which will raise the power by 2 so (m.m). Thus the units in the initial equation for drag force remain unchanged and there is no need to divide or multiply by anything. This represents the total drag force on the object since you are adding the forces over all the differential areas (dx dy).